# cypher query: combination of collect and foreach

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i want to write a query in cypher in order to find how many actors have acted in all of the movies in which brock lesnar has acted. My plan is to collect all the movies in which brocklesnar has acted and then loop through each of the movies and see if there are common actors in all of the movies. I am not able to write the query for the same. can anybody give me some suggestions to how to approach this problem?

```
match (a:`ACTOR` {name: 'Brock Lesnar'})-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:`MOVIES`) collect(m.title) as      movies foreach(c in movies return (actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(c))
```

this is what i have written so far. i know it is not right but this is where i am having the problem to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cypher query below will give you an ordered list of coactors of Brock Lesnar using your optional schema.

```
MATCH (actor:ACTOR { name: "Brock Lesnar" })-[:ACTS_IN]->(movie:MOVIES)
WITH collect(movie) as movies, actor
MATCH (coactors:ACTOR)-[:ACTS_IN]->()<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor)
WHERE ALL(movie in movies WHERE (movie)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(coactors))
RETURN DISTINCT coactors.name
```

Comment: it returns zero rows. can you tell me why are you doing distinct? also let me repeat my question, i want the name of actors who have acted in "all" lesnar movies

Comment: totally incorrect, i am posting the correct answer, i figured it out

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out

Answer (score -1):

this is the query i have created. it first collects all the movie in which lesner has acted. and then all the actors are checked if they have acted in all of the movies or not

```
MATCH (actor:ACTOR{name:'Brock Lesnar'})-[:ACTS_IN]->(movie)
with actor,collect(movie.title) as movieCollection
WHERE ALL (movies IN movieCollection WHERE (actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(movies)) AND NOT  actor.name = "Brock Lesnar"
return actor.name
```

Comment: This Cypher query will not actually work. You're collecting on the movie.title and then you are performing a predicate operation with a path expression that will return an error.

I've updated my query, and fixed my mistake. I suggest using this query.

Comment: my query is correct except for the fact that i need to put a different "ACTOR" than actor whose name is equal to brock lesner. yes you areright, you have now framed the write query. dont downgrade my answer, as my answer gave you the idea of using "all" and come up with a better query. in the first attempt you also got it wrong